# Synology's WiFi stops working frequently: TX Deauth pkt

Tags: wireless-networking, router, synology

I've got a Synology TC1900ac with a curious problem. WiFi is working fine most of the time, but sometimes all wireless connected devices lose the connectivity. The appear to still have a connection, but even `ping 192.168.1.1` fails. New devices can't connect to Wifi at all.

I can't find any error message in the web interface. Disabling and re-enabling Wifi solves the problem, sometimes.

Luckily, Synology gives root access via SSH, so I've been able to see the logs on the devices. This is what I've found that's maybe relevant:

```
2017 12 24 18 45 26 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 6983.530000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [f4:f5:d8:08:9c:94], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 45 30 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 6987.460000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 45 32 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 6990.200000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [84:98:66:89:fc:f5], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 45 42 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 6999.830000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 45 55 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7012.810000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 45 55 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7012.870000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [7]
2017 12 24 18 46 08 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7026.090000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 46 20 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7037.670000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 46 32 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7049.780000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 46 54 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7071.360000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 47 16 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7094.120000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 47 29 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7106.440000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 47 38 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7116.070000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [f4:f5:d8:08:9c:94], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
2017 12 24 18 47 38 SynologyRouter kernel: [ 7116.170000] [SYNO_WIFI] TX Deauth pkt: AP [00:11:32:4d:82:2f] -> STA [94:65:2d:7a:f0:b7], sa [00:11:32:4d:82:2f], reason: [15]
```

I've tried to find out what `TX Deauth pkt` might be, but I couldn't find a resource with a clear explanation.

How can I find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this logs, there is a bug in recent firmware of Synology's router (both RT1900ac and RT2600ac are affected.

https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=137668